# htaccess regex to match username url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url

I need to use username in url like

**domain.com/username**

so I put this line as the last line in htaccess to avoid any conflict with other pages.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)/?(i.html)?$  index.php?module=profile&username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

but the problem is the line below is ignored when I request **domain.com/manage/** and continue to the last line and that's makes the conflict.

```
RewriteRule ^manage/?(i.html)?$  manage.php?module=manage [QSA,L]
```

is there any way to make the last patter do this :

/**(staticname|or any other static page's name|)**/i.html = **NOT OK**

/**fstaticname**/i.html = **OK** as a username

/**staticnamef**/i.html = **OK** as a username

/**staticname.f**/i.html = **OK** as a username

/**staticname** = **OK** as a username

if not is there any other solution ?

thank you!

Edit :

I Get this regex

```
^((?!(manage|notifs|admin)\/?$)([a-zA-Z0-9.]+))\/?(i.html)?$
```

and it's work fine in regex tester but not with htaccess.

Comment: So `/i.html` is always present when page name starts with `f` or ends with `.?f`?

Comment: @anubhava, no it's not always present and it has any relation with the page name.